# How do I stop my son picking at his scabs

Tags: behavior, middle-childhood, habits

My 9 year old son has developed a habit of picking at a scab on his forehead. Unfortunately plasters just do no stick there for more than an hour or three (sweaty).

How can I get him to stop this as the scab has not healed for a very long time?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially I had to add some consequences to the action.

In this case I pulled out the big guns and said that if he picked at the scab again I would ban him from all video games until it healed. So far that has motivated him to monitor his own behaviour, even to the point where he put plasters on the wound himself.

The injuries healed several days later.